# React Trying to edit input but got an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on the edit/update the prices in the price list in my React app. I'm almost close but was unable to input any changes. Every time I tried to change the price in the input, I get an error saying "TypeError: onChange is not a function"...

I'm trying to write my code that's almost similar to this tutorial: https://medium.com/the-andela-way/handling-user-input-in-react-crud-1396e51a70bf#8858

So far, I was able to toggle the price between input field and back but I'm trying to edit the input to save any changes...What am I missing? I kept checking between my code and this tutorial to make sure everything is working...

Here's my code (functions) in the Parent component, `PriceForm.js`:

```
toggleItemEditing = index => {
    this.setState({
      priceArr: this.state.priceArr.map((item, itemIndex) => {
        if (itemIndex === index) {
          return {
            ...item,
            isEditing: !item.isEditing
          }
        }
        return item;
      })
    });
  };

  handlePriceUpdate = (event, index) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const number = target.number;
    this.setState({
      priceArr: this.state.priceArr.map((item, itemIndex) => {
        if (itemIndex === index) {
          return {
            ...item,
            [number]: value
          }
        }
        return item;
      })
    });
    console.log("price update", event);
  };
```

and where it's called in:

```
{this.state.priceArr.map((props, index) => (
              <PriceBox
                {...props}
                key={props.date}
                toggleEditing={this.toggleItemEditing}
                handleDeletePrice={this.handleDeletePrice}
                onChange={this.handlePriceUpdate}
              />
            ))}
```

And here's my code for the Child component, `SinglePriceBox.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class SinglePricebox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    isInEditMode: false,
    todaydate: this.props.date
  };

  this.toggleEditPriceSubmission = this.toggleEditPriceSubmission.bind(this);
}

toggleEditPriceSubmission() {
  this.setState(state => ({ isInEditMode: !state.isInEditMode }));
}


  render() {
    const { isInEditMode, onChange, index } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="pricebox">
        <article className="pricetable">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td className="date-width">{this.props.date}</td>
                <td className="price-width">
                {isInEditMode ? (
                    <input type="text" name="number" value={this.props.number} onChange={event => onChange(event, index)} />
                  ) : (
                    this.props.number
                  )}
                </td>
                <td className="editing-btn">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="edit-btn"
                    onClick={this.toggleEditPriceSubmission}
                  >
                    {isInEditMode ? "Save" : "Edit"}
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                {this.props.handleDeletePrice && (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="delete-btn"
                    onClick={() => this.props.handleDeletePrice(this.props.date)}
                    >
                      X
                    </button>
                    )}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </article>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can check out my demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kikidesignnet/caissa. You will be able to check out the error if you click on `Prices` button, then click on `Edit` button to change the price in the input field that appears.

Comment: you don't have onChange in state. what is the function you want to call when there is change in input?

Answer (score 1):

In the following line:

```
<input type="text" name="number" value={this.props.number} onChange={event => onChange(event, index)} />
```

You're calling this.state.onChange but there is no onChange in your state:

```
this.state = {
    isInEditMode: false,
    todaydate: this.props.date
  };
```

After looking at your codesandbox, it seems that onChange is passed as a props to PriceBox, so you should do this in SinglePriceBox render():

```
const { isInEditMode, index } = this.state;
const { onChange } = this.props;
```

This will remove the error you were having, but the update still doesn't work because target.number is undefined in PriceForm.handlePriceUpdate :(

However target.name is defined and equal to 'number' which is a valid key in your price list

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class SinglePricebox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    isInEditMode: false,
    todaydate: this.props.date
  };

  this.toggleEditPriceSubmission = this.toggleEditPriceSubmission.bind(this);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

toggleEditPriceSubmission() {
  this.setState(state => ({ isInEditMode: !state.isInEditMode }));
}

handleChange = (e, index) => {
  // write your code here
}


  render() {
    const { isInEditMode, index } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="pricebox">
        <article className="pricetable">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td className="date-width">{this.props.date}</td>
                <td className="price-width">
                {isInEditMode ? (
                    <input type="text" name="number" value={this.props.number} onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, index)} />
                  ) : (
                    this.props.number
                  )}
                </td>
                <td className="editing-btn">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="edit-btn"
                    onClick={this.toggleEditPriceSubmission}
                  >
                    {isInEditMode ? "Save" : "Edit"}
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                {this.props.handleDeletePrice && (
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="delete-btn"
                    onClick={() => this.props.handleDeletePrice(this.props.date)}
                    >
                      X
                    </button>
                    )}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </article>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in how you pass your function as a prop. You should pass the function call in this way:

```
<PriceBox
   {...props}
   [...]
   onChange={(e) => this.handlePriceUpdate(e, index)}
/>
```

Then call it in your child component:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  [...]
  onChange={event => this.props.onChange(event, index)} 
/>
```

Also, I would not using index here, I would rather use an ID from your object instead